# Printing triangle of numbers in C++ in a specific way?

Tags: c++, loops, printing

I have a program where I have to print triangle of numbers in a specific way. My program prints for example for 5 the following:

```
1
1 2
1 2 3
1 2 3 4
1 2 3 4 5
```

I want to print them the following way:

```
         1
       1 2
     1 2 3
   1 2 3 4
 1 2 3 4 5
```

I tried with setw() using the iomanip library but it did not work. My question is  how can I fix that.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int n,br=1;
int main()
{
    cin>>n;
    while (br<=n)
    {
        for(int i=1; i<=br; i++)
        {

            cout<<i<<' ';
        }
        br++;
        cout<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "int n,br=1;" - Why as global variables? Always *avoid* globals whenever you can (and here you trivially *can* avoid them).

Comment: [These manipulators](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/left) might be helpful to know about. Learn how you could use them together with [`std::setw`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setw). Experiment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code !
Also I am attach the output of the code.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int count=1;
    int flag=0;
    for(int i=1;i<=5;i++)
    {
        for(int j=5;j>0;j--)
        {
            if(i==j)
            {
                flag=1;
            }
            if(flag==1)
            {
                cout<<"\t"<<count;
                count++;
            }
            else
            {

                cout<<"\t";
            }

        }
        flag=0;
        count=1;
        cout<<"\n";
    }


}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can add a for loop nested in your while before your number output loop. This loop can then output some number of spaces.

I'm not going to give you the code so that you can do some of the work yourself, but if you're having trouble, take a piece of paper and write how many spaces should be on each line. See if you can find a pattern or formula for the numbers and then the code should come easier.

Answer (score 0):

You can try a loop for space below your i loop.

```
for(int j=1;j<=n-br;j++)
    cout<<"  ";
```

This should decrease space linearly as value of br keeps increasing.